# Change cursor to 'move' on 'dragstart'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the cursor to 'move' after the dragging starts. I tried setting the `dropEffect` property to `move` but that doesn't work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

How can I change the `cursor` to `move` only AFTER the `dragstart` event fires?

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
console.log(button);

button.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);

function dragStart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", 'hello');
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
  console.log(e);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" draggable="true">Drag Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I had to change the cursor on `dragstart` and revert it back on `dragend`

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
console.log(button);

button.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
button.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);

function dragStart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", 'hello');
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
  e.target.style.cursor='move';
  console.log(e);
}

function dragEnd(e) {
  e.target.style.cursor='default';
}
```

```html
<button type="button" draggable="true">Test Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can read `dropEffect` is only available for when the user hovers over a **drop target**:

> Within event handlers for `dragenter` and `dragover` events, **`dropEffect` should be modified if a different action is desired than the action that the user is requesting.**

— [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/dropEffect)

It says `dragenter`, `dragover` but not `dragstart`.

Comment: You are right. I am going to post an answer to show how I achieved the effect I wanted